# Multisig wallet staking via Polkadot-JS UI failed

Tags: polkadot, staking, polkadot-js-extension, multisig

I created a 2/3 multisig wallet and staked 500 DOT with it, but I received this error message.

> This could mean your nomination has not been applied to any validator in the active set by the election algorithm or it has been applied against a validator who is either oversubscribed or chilled.

[image]

I checked [Nominate](https://staking.polkadot.network/#/nominate) page and found that the minimum to earn rewards is 450.17 DOT, but I staked 500 DOT. I tried to stake twice, the first time I chose 10 nominators, and the second time I chose 2 nominators, but both attempts failed. I waited for a couple of days, but it kept waiting for nominations. I confirmed these nominators were available and healthy.

How can I solve this issue? Doesn’t the multisig wallet support staking?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're nominating only 2 addresses with the minimum amount. Could you please provide more information about your nominations and how you chose them? Have you checked to ensure they're not oversubscribed and are being selected to be "active" in validating eras?

Comment: The names of the two nominees are as follows: IOSG VENTURES (1RG5T6zGY4XovW75mTgpH6Bx7Y6uwwMmPToMCJSdMwdm4EW) and IOSG VENTURES/02 (14zybcYPYQEEmmZUnvCpTnAE6Tm2uRKWG4xPmDfHZn9Yjvrq). And I already checked, they are valid.

Answer (score 0):

the nomination pool you trying to nominate to is oversubscribed or chilled. You can choose another pool

Comment: I've tried three times, and I find it hard to believe that all the nominators I've chosen are invalid. Most recently, I selected Coinbase Cloud.